# Can we use only initialstate and null state in Buildgraph method of caa?

Tags: c++, catia, caa

Can we use only initialstate and null state?If yes,how will it behave?

Comment: In command's build graph you can use Cancel state and of course define your own states and state transition diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the encyclopedia

> The command is never in the initial state that automatically skips to the first state.

But when you read further (in the code example) :

```
CATDialogState *stStartState = GetInitialState("stStartPointId");
```

These are not the same states. In other words, GetInitialState returns you the **first** working state of your diagram (that will be reached automatically at command activation from the **initial** state) that can be associated with agents, be the source or target of any transition, as any other state that you further create with **AddDialogState**

You will have to reconsider your question then.

- can I have a command with the first state and null : **yes**. It could be a single user action command like selecting something, that leads to the null state, or associated with a dialog : the transition would loop on the first state as long as the user keeps selecting valid stuff, that would for example be displayed in a dialog's field, then the user would choose OK or Cancel, leading to null or cancel state
- can I have a command with the initial state and null : **no**. Since you wouldn't be able to create any transition, as you never have a way to manipulate that initial state.